# Accessing Router With Static IP

Tags: router, ubuntu-server, static-ip

I have a Ubuntu server that runs behind a Linksys router with a static ip address. I had been accessing the router settings remotely, but it didn't really seem safe to have it available over the internet. Now that I've disabled remote access, I can't figure out how to get into the router again. I tried connecting via ethernet to the router's standard ip (192.168.1.1), but to no avail.

Is there any way to get into the router's settings without having to reset it or disconnect from the server? If I do have to reset the router, is there a better way to set it up?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read our FAQ next time, this question is more suited to our sister site superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks for moderating Chopper3, but I'm not sure I completely understand why this question isn't fit for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure the ip addresss of the router is 192.168.1.1 and you did correctly set the ip address of the computer to a 192.168.1.x address? Disabling the remote access does not usually cause an issue with internal management capability.

Your best option may be to just reset to defaults and reconfigure. Sometimes unplugging a Linksys for about 1 minute and then plugging it back in does the trick as well.

As for advice, I would set the router to allow only LAN side management and then forward remote access through to a computer on the LAN via RDP or VNC. From that computer you would be able to manage the Linksys internally.

Cheers!